# Using RequireJS with TypeScript and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, typescript

I'm about to rip my brains out trying to define an Angular module in TypeScript while using RequireJS. Have looked all over for a solution while spending days trying to figure it all out to no avail. Please help, I'm so confused!

I'm not using Visual Studio, but rather WebStorm. This shouldn't really matter however.
I'm using TS 9.1, AngularJS 1.0.7, RequireJS 2.1.8.
I've also tried using DefinitelyTyped's angular.d.td, but it's not helping.

Does anyone have a simple example of a TS angular app module for app init, with another TS angular module that has a controller, being loaded with RequireJS, referencing "DefinitelyTyped/angularjs/angular.d.ts", and calling 'angular.module' to define themselves, and then referencing the controller in a web page?

Please, help.... I'm burning in TypeScript, RequireJS, AngularJS module hell.

Comment: Personally I don't see *any* benefit for using requirejs anymore for the internals of your app. Will be doing a video tutorial on my current workflow soon. But if you know grunt you can look at : https://github.com/basarat/video-angular-typescript which uses https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-ts

Comment: I don't use Angular, but I use Dojo (which has its own version of RequireJS) with TypeScript.  Took a couple of tries to figure out.  Some of the details are a bit tricky, especially since TypeScript defaults to CommonJS-style modules which are incompatible with RequireJS.  You can look into my https://github.com/schungx/Dojo-TypeScript for some inspiration.  I have a sort of manual which details how to use TypeScript with Dojo, and you should get some ideas from there.

Answer (score 22):

I was able to use these 3 technologies together. I added `angular.d.ts` and other files from DefinitelyTyped to my Visual Studio project but I also needed to add module declarations using `declare module` statements. That's because angular definitions from DefinitelyTyped are written for usage without AMD/requirejs. Maybe it is better to use jquery and angular without AMD (load it using `<script>` tag) and use AMD only for application modules but anyway here is example extracted from my project:

### index.html

```
<script src="webjars/requirejs/2.1.11/require.js" data-main="js/requireMain"></script>
```

### requireMain.ts

Main file for requirejs. It is TypeScript file but doesn't use `import` syntax and rather uses usual requirejs syntax. It also declares angular modules.

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '../js',
    paths: {
        'jquery': '../webjars/jquery/1.11.0/jquery',
        'angular': '../webjars/angularjs/1.2.16/angular',
        'angular-route': '../webjars/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-route',
        'angular-resource': '../webjars/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-resource',
        'angular-ui-bootstrap': '../webjars/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls',
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery': { exports: 'jquery' },
        'angular': { exports: 'angular', dep: ['jquery'] },
        'angular-route': { exports: 'angular-route', deps: ['angular'] },
        'angular-resource': { exports: 'angular-resource', deps: ['angular'] },
        'angular-ui-bootstrap': { exports: 'angular-ui-bootstrap', deps: ['angular'] },
    },
});

// TypeScript declarations useful for importing angular modules
declare module 'angular' {
    var angular: ng.IAngularStatic;
    export = angular;
}
declare module 'angular-route' {
}
declare module 'angular-resource' {
}
declare module 'angular-ui-bootstrap' {
}

require(['jquery', 'angular', 'angular-route', 'angular-resource', 'angular-ui-bootstrap', 'bootstrap', 
    'application', 'routes'],
    function ($: JQueryStatic, angular: ng.IAngularStatic, angularRoute, angularResource, angularUiBootstrap,
        application, routes) {
        $(function () {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['application']);
        });
    });
```

### application.ts

```
import angular = require('angular');
import angularRoute = require('angular-route');
import angularResource = require('angular-resource');
import angularUiBootstrap = require('angular-ui-bootstrap');

var application = angular.module('application', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap']);
export = application
```

### routes.ts

```
import application = require('application');
import myModule = require('myModule');

application.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/myPage', { controller: myModule.MyPageCtrl, templateUrl: 'partials/myPage.html' }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/myPage' });
});
```

### myModule.ts

```
import application = require('application');
import angularUiBootstrap = require('angular-ui-bootstrap');
import myService = require('myService');

export interface MyPageCtrlScope {
    someData: string;
    someAction: () => void;
}

export class MyPageCtrl {

    constructor(public $scope: MyPageCtrlScope, private PersonService: myService.PersonResourceClass, private $modal: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalService) {

        PersonService.additionalAction({}).$promise.then(
            (person) => {
                this.$scope.someData = person.email;
            });

        $scope.someAction = this.someAction.bind(this);
    }

    someAction() {
        this.$modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'dialog.html'
        }).result.then(
            () => {
                this.$scope.someData = 'something else';
            });
    }

}
```

### myService.ts

```
import application = require('application');
import angularResource = require('angular-resource');

export interface Person {
    id?: number;
    email?: string;
}

export interface PersonResource extends Person, ng.resource.IResource<PersonResource> {
}

export interface PersonResourceClass extends ng.resource.IResourceClass<PersonResource> {
    additionalAction(person: Person): PersonResource;
}

application.factory('PersonService', function ($resource: ng.resource.IResourceService, apiUrl: string): PersonResourceClass {
    return <PersonResourceClass> $resource(apiUrl + '/person/:id', { id: "@id" }, {
        'additionalAction': { method: 'POST', url: apiUrl + '/person/:id/additionalAction' },
    });
});
```

Comment: Very nice. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! I really like the structure of your solution but I get [this error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=application&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20) in application.js

Comment: Do you have a git repository with the whole solution that I could have a look at?

Comment: @Juancho unfortunately no, I don't have public project with these technologies.

Comment: This is relatively old answer and I think today it should be possible to use angular definitions directly (without "declare module" statements in `requireMain.ts`).

Answer (score 3):

There are no stoppers in this scenario that I am aware of, we are using in a large app internally. Publicly I have this small sample : https://github.com/basarat/TypeScriptDeepDive that uses all three.

To help you debug I am sure there is some non TS issue you are having with RequireJS + Angular. The simplest way to narrow it down is to define the following variables:

```
declare var angular:any;
declare var define:any; 
declare var require:any;
```

This will allow you to use straight up TypeScript as though it was javascript, at least for requirejs/angularjs.

Then you can sort out your issues and pull in the type definitions for angular / requirejs.