# Typescript RequireJs Shortcuts + Navigation

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript

I am having these requireJs options defined:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/js/',
    paths: {
        jquery: '/components/jquery/dist/jquery',
        foundation: '/components/foundation/js/foundation',
        fastclick: '/components/fastclick/lib/fastclick',
        angular: '/components/angular/angular',
        angularRoute: '/components/angular-route/angular-route',
        socketIO: '/components/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io'
    },

    shim: {
        'foundation': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'fastclick']
        },
        'angular': {'exports': 'angular'},
        'angularRoute': ['angular']
    },
    priority: [
        'angular'
    ]

});
```

these are working all fine, if i am using requireJs in the javascript syntax. Then the base url and all these nice shortcuts for external libraries work.

But I am asking you now if i can also use these shortcuts in the Typescript way.
Because If i am saying: for instance in a file

```
import angular = require('angular');
```

it isnot importing the file. I am ofc compiling the source with the amd option.

Also can someone provide me links how to navigate through the project with these import statement. 
[image: my folder structure for client-side code]

this structure is what i am using for my current project. There I have a client (public) folder and if i want to access a js file for instance in the browser. I have to write: localhost/js/file.js
Now when i am using requireJs in the js syntax I can easily write things like controllers/userController and it navigated to the right folder, but how do i have to navigate within my import/require?
currently I have to use relative paths from the file i am using the import but that is not very wise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this to make it work :)

```
/// <reference path="./types/angular/angular.d.ts" />
declare module 'angular'{
    var angular:ng.IAngularStatic;
    export = angular;
}

// now you can do: 
import angular = require('angular');
```

Comment: I did similar thing. You can see more detailed example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171045/using-requirejs-with-typescript-and-angularjs/23737409#23737409