# best way to import external javascript with typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, typescript

Currently I have 2 different ways in case I want to load in external code into my typescript file.

If i refer to another typescript file I have to write:

```
import object = require('./path/to/the/internal/module');
```

but if I am loading code from an existing js file, I have to do it like that:

```
/// <reference path="./types/angular/angular.d.ts" />
///<amd-dependency path="angular"/>
var angular:ng.IAngularStatic = require('angular');
```

is there no way to make these two things look the same? So that i can for instance do something like that:

```
/// <reference path="./types/angular/angular.d.ts" />
import angular = require('angular');
```

btw do you recommend me to load the external things like angular, jquery,... via requirejs or globally on its own script tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just declare it as an external module

```
/// <reference path="./types/angular/angular.d.ts" />
declare module 'angular'{
    var angular:ng.IAngularStatic;
    export = angular;
}

// now you can do: 
import angular = require('angular');
```

Comment: I did similar thing. You can see more detailed example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171045/using-requirejs-with-typescript-and-angularjs/23737409#23737409